# How to calculate this integral? Integrate[BesselJ[0, x - BesselJZero[0, 1]]/x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I tried to calculate the following integral, but it returned unevaluated.

```
In[1]:= Integrate[BesselJ[0, x - BesselJZero[0, 1]]/x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Out[1]= Integrate[BesselJ[0, x - BesselJZero[0, 1]]/x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Any ideas how to make Mathematica calculate it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
In[1]:= Integrate[BesselJ[0, x]/(x + BesselJZero[0, 1]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Out[1]= Pi StruveH[0, BesselJZero[0, 1]]
```